# Parameterized Type Parameters?

Tags: java, generics, nested-generics

I'm trying to create library with a container that releases instances of its contained objects according to descriptors it is passed.  I'd like to make it so the descriptor determines the type of the returned object, but the descriptor can specify a bounded type.  How do I implement this?  For example the closest I can get is:

```
/*Block 1 - First Attempt.  Compiles, but forces user to cast*/
interface ItemDescriptor<I> {
    Class<? extends I> getType();
}

interface ArchiveContainer<I, D extends ItemDescriptor<? extends I>> {
    Iterable<? extends D> getDescriptors();
    I getItem(D descriptor);
}

//Implementations
class ChannelItemDescriptor<I extends ByteChannel> implements ItemDescriptor<I>
{
    final Class<? extends I>  type;

    ChannelItemDescriptor(Class<I> type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    @Override Class<? extends I> getType() {return type;}
}

class ChannelArchive implements ArchiveContainer<ByteChannel, ChannelItemDescriptor<? extends ByteChannel>> {
    @Override ByteChannel getItem(ChannelItemDescriptor<? extends ByteChannel> descriptor) {...}
}
```

The above code compiles, but the problem is `ChannelArchive`'s `getItem` can return `SeekableByteChannel`s as well.  The user of this library knows this at compile time (because they know the type parameter of the descriptor), so I'm trying to avoid adding a method parameter of type `Class` for forcing the user to explicitly cast the returned value to `SeekableByteChannel` when necessary.  I can't figure out how to get `getItem` to return a specific subtype of `ByteChannel` without forcing the user to cast.  I want to do this:

```
/*Block 2 - Test code*/
ChannelArchive archive = ...;
ChannelItemDescriptor<SeekableByteChannel> desc = ...;
ChannelItemDescriptor<ByteChannel> otherDesc = ...;
SeekableByteChannel sbc = archive.getItem(desc);
SeekableByteChannel sbc = archive.getItem(otherDesc); //Should fail to compile, or compile with warning
ByteChannel bc = archive.getItem(otherDesc);
```

I *could* add a `Class<? extends I>` parameter to each method, but the code for the method would completely ignore `Class` method parameter!  It's only purpose would be to help the compiler infer types.  I think it just obfuscates the code so much that it would be easier to just have the user use `instanceof` checks and casts.

I've tried this:

```
/*Block 3 - Failed attempt.*/
class ChannelArchive implements ArchiveContainer<ByteChannel, ChannelItemDescriptor<? extends ByteChannel>> {
    //Won't compile, getItem doesn't override
    @Override <II extends ByteChannel> II getItem(ChannelItemDescriptor<II> descriptor) {...}
}
```

but that doesn't work:  `ChannelArchive is not abstract and does not override abstract method getItem(ChannelItemDescriptor<? extends ByteChannel>) in ArchiveContainer`.  I assume this is because the second type parameter `<II extends ByteChannel>` has different type erasure than `<? extends ByteChannel>`?

I've also tried this, which compiles:

```
/*Block 4 - Almost specific enough*/
interface ArchiveContainer<I, D extends ItemDescriptor<? extends I>> {
    Iterable<? extends D> getDescriptors();
    <II extends I, DD extends ItemDescriptor<II>> II getItem(DD descriptor);
}

class ChannelArchive implements ArchiveContainer<ByteChannel, ChannelItemDescriptor<? extends ByteChannel>> {
    @Override <II extends ByteChannel, DD extends ItemDescriptor<II>> II getItem(DD descriptor) {...}
}
```

Even though it compiles, it won't *really* work because I need a `ChannelItemDescriptor` inside that method, and the resulting cast would defeat the purpose of using the added type-safety of generics.

I don't see why I can't do it, because the right types are known at compile time.  What I really need on that `ArchiveContainer` interface is a parameterized type parameter, like: `<II extends I, DD extends D<II>>`.  What am I doing wrong?

NOTE:  I don't actually use `ByteChannel` and `SeekableByteChannel`, but what I do use is quite similiar.

---

That's to ruakh, I settled on the code in block 4.  In my case, its highly unlikely the user would send the wrong sublcass of `ItemDescriptor` in a call to a `getItem`, especially because the descriptors are all returned from the `ArchiveContainer` itself via `getDescriptors`!

Comment: Your code -- even your top example -- is very ill-formed, which makes it hard to figure out what you're trying to do. For example, `class <I extends ByteChannel> ChannelItemDescriptor<I> implements ItemDescriptor<I>` is completely invalid syntax; maybe you meant `class ChannelItemDescriptor<I extends ByteChannel> implements ItemDescriptor<I>`? Likewise `class ChannelArchive<ByteChannel, ChannelItemDescriptor<? extends ByteChannel>>`; maybe you meant `class ChannelArchive implements ArchiveContainer<ByteChannel, ChannelItemDescriptor<? extends ByteChannel>>`? [continued]

Comment: [continued] Your question implies that the only problem with your top example is that `ChannelArchive.getItem(...)` has a wider return-type than you'd like. If you can post a version of your top example that *actually* has only that problem, it will be much easier to help you.

Comment: The top block of code has that problem.  The second block demonstrates it.  The third and fourth blocks are failed attempts, posted with the hope that they clarify what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: My point is that the top block of code has *lots* of problems. You clearly did not try to compile it. But regardless, I think I understand now what you're trying to do, and have posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this code, which is (almost?) the same as your third attempt, is as good as you're going to get:

```
// in ArchiveContainer:
<II extends I, DD extends ItemDescriptor<II>> II getItem(DD descriptor);

// in ChannelArchive:
public <II extends ByteChannel, DD extends ItemDescriptor<II>>
    II getItem(DD descriptor)
    { ... }
```

Generics do offer a way to declare a type variable with two separate upper bounds:

```
public <T extends Foo & Bar> Foo fooBar(T t) { ... }
```

but apparently that's not allowed when one of the upper bounds is a type-parameter rather than a class or interface:

> Type variables have an optional bound, *T & I<sub>1</sub> ... I<sub>n</sub>*. The bound consists of **either** a type variable, **or** a class or interface type *T* possibly followed by further interface types *I<sub>1</sub> , ..., I<sub>n</sub>*. […] It is a compile-time error if any of the types *I<sub>1</sub> ... I<sub>n</sub>* is a class type or type variable. [[link](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#108850)]

(emphases mine). I don't know why this is.

But I don't think this should be a big problem. Note that, even after `Map` was genericized to `Map<K,V>`, its `get` method still took type `Object`. Naturally that method will always return `null` if you pass in a reference to an object that's not of type `K` (since such an object should never have been inserted into the map), but this doesn't harm type-safety.

Comment: The second that third attempts don't compile.  But yes, I tried the two separate upper bounds, and was baffled that didn't work.  It would have been perfect.  The first attempt is... satisfactory.  I'm just trying to improve it.  With the Map example you gave, the *library* code handles casting and type checking.  In my problem, the *user* code has to check and cast.  Or they call a static utility method that does it.  My example is more like... calling `get` with a parameterized key type and expecting the value to be a specific subclass of the value type.

Comment: @MutantPlatypus: Er, I have a version locally that *does* compile. I thought it was the same as what I was calling your "second attempt" (though I now realize that you call it your "third attempt"), but maybe there's some difference? I'll edit my answer to include actual code that does compile.

Comment: [continued] like so:
`interface KeyType<P> {}`
`interface ValueType<V> {}`
`class FooMap<KeyType<? extends Exception>, ValueType<? extends Exception> {`
    `<V extends Exception> V get(KeyType<V>) {...}}`

Comment: And I've updated my question to explain why that won't work for me. :)  Thanks for your help, it is a good idea, and may work for others.  But my problem is the `DD extends ItemDescriptor<II>`.  `DD` needs to erase to a `ChannelItemDescriptor` to be useful.  Otherwise I have to cast it, making the generics not type-safe.  I thought Map did that to maintain compatibility with pre-generics code, and couldn't declare a `get(K key)` because that erases to `get(Object key)`, causing a name clash?

Comment: @MutantPlatypus: But the fact that `get(K key)` erases to `get(Object key` is exactly why the `get` method *could* have been changed without breaking compatibility. (Note that `put` *was* changed from `put(Object key, Object value)` to `put(K key, V value)`.) The reason it wasn't changed is that there's no harm in a lookup method that's able to look up nonexistent objects: those objects won't exist.

Comment: @MutantPlatypus: I've read your updated question, and my answer is the same. The cast to `ChannelItemDescriptor` *is* type-safe, because the only part that can't be checked at runtime is the type argument, which is checked at compile-time by virtue of the lower bound on `DD`.

Comment: But it's not.  At first I thought, "Ah-ha!  That's basically allowing two lower bounds on `DD`, one specified in the type argument declaration, the other in the method parameter declaration and class type parameter."  But it doesn't work that way.  The second block of code (now labeled "Test Code") compiles without warning using the definitions in the fourth block ("Even Lower Bounds"), but when run throws a ClassCastException.  Is there a way I can send you the code I'm using?  I don't have enough reputation to chat.

Comment: @MutantPlatypus: If you post your e-mail address (temporarily), I'll send you a message.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8085/discussion-between-mutant-platypus-and-ruakh)

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is probably not what you want to hear, but even though Java generics look syntactically like C++ templates, they differ quite a bit in how they work.

Look up `java type erasure` in your favorite search engine.
Just because a type is known at compile-time does not, unfortunately, mean that the type is recoverable at runtime, or even during later compile phases.

Comment: I don't have any experience with C++ templates, and I understand that type-erasure is why I can't specify a more specific type on `getItem` in `ChannelArchive` (it erases to the same signature).  "Just because a type is known at compile-time does not, unfortunately, mean that the type is recoverable at runtime..." yeah, I knew that "... or even during later compile phases."   Hmmm, that's new to me.  What constitutes a "later compile phase"?